# How can I print the Firebase array elements that I see in the console, to display them on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first time using Firebase. So I'm kind of stuck at at point where I can see the data I've fetched from the database in the console but I don't have a clue how to access the data elements and maybe display them.

I used a react hook to retrieve the data.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const dbRef=ref(db,"thisIsMyDatabaseString");
    onValue(dbRef,(snapshot)=>{
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    })
  },[]);
```

I can see the array elements

[image: like this]

I don't know how to maybe display them in a Grid (I'm using material UI).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Firebase's built-in `forEach` on the snapshot:

```
const dbRef=ref(db,"thisIsMyDatabaseString");
onValue(dbRef,(snapshot)=>{
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    console.log(child.val());
  })
})
```

Note that such sequential numeric indexes are a common anti-pattern in Firebase, so I recommend also reading [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).